# NSAttributedString: Strikethrough text with replacement text above it

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I am trying to draw an `NSAttributedString` (actually, a constructed `NSMutableAttributedString`) where the "original" text has been struck and replacement text inserted above it (I'm trying to replicate the look/feel of an Ancient Greek manuscript).

My technique is a combination of `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` with `NSKernAttributeName`, but it appears that using a negative value for `NSKernAttributeName` "wipes away" the strikethrough of the text, even if the characters don't overlap.

If I put an extra space after the "A" character (in the original text), the "A" gets the strikethrough, but the "EI" is also offset to the right. So, it appears that the offset/kerning of the "EI" text affects how much of the strikethrough actually occurs.

Here's what I'd like to reproduce (I don't care about the angle; it's not about a picture-perfect reproduction; just the gist):

[image: strikethrough original]

Here's what is currently happening:

[image: strikethrough output]

This is when I add an extra space after the strikethrough:

[image: strikethrough plus extra space]

So, the only other thing I can think of would be to render a separate `NSAttributedString` in the correct place, separate from the current one, but I have no idea how to calculate the location of a specific character in an `NSAttributedString` when it's drawn. I'm drawing to a PDF, not to any on-screen control like a `UILabel`. Alternatively, I could draw the "strikethrough" myself as a line, but that seems to still require knowing the coordinates for the text in question, which is calculated on-the-fly, and I hope to use this method to reproduce a large sample of ancient texts, which means doing it by hand just isn't a good answer here.

Anything I'm missing, or any out-of-the-box ideas to try?

Comment: I'd say there is nothing all done. I'm afraid you'd have to "draw it" yourself with CoreText and override the drawings methods to your custom needs.

Comment: @Larme Any suggestions on how to do that, or how to calculate the location of a specific character or range of characters?